# iOS Program Flow - Wait for user input

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS programming, and am attempting to find out how to interrupt program flow to wait for a response.

Basically I want to send an email from my application, and provided what the data is, I want to prompt the user to add more information.

ie:

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {

MyManagedObject *myObj = nil;

//Retrieve from the database.
NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyManagedObject" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [ctx executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSUInteger count = [array count]; // May be 0 if the object has been deleted.
if (count > 0) {
    myObj = (MyManagedObject *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
}

 //Recipients
NSArray *toRecipents = [[NSArray alloc]init];
// Email Subject
NSString *emailTitle = [@"Report for Month of: " stringByAppendingString: dateString] ;
// Email Content
NSString *messageBody = @"";
if(myObj != nil) {
    if (myObj.firstName) {
        messageBody = [messageBody stringByAppendingString:[@"\nHello " stringByAppendingString: myObj.firstName]];
        toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myObj.emailAddress];
    }
}
messageBody = [messageBody stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nBelow is my text...."];
messageBody = [messageBody stringByAppendingString:[@"\nMore Information...: " stringByAppendingString: myObj.moreInfo]];

NSString *addInfo = OPEN WINDOW FOR USER TO ADD INFO

if (addInfo != nil) {
messageBody = [messageBody stringByAppendingString:[@"\nAdditional Information...: " stringByAppendingString: addInfo]];
}

... send the email
}
```

I am unsure if this is possible without a callback.  Basically I want to interrupt the flow, put up an overlay and wait for it to close before completing the email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, what you trying to do is showing a custom dialog or alertview and only on its return value, the code should execute further.

So lets say, If you display a `UIAlertView` with `UITextView` inside for adding more information, you should move your `sendEmail` method to the callback of alertview's button. Similarly if you are going for some custom dialog, then you should write a callback in your custom dialog to main window and then in that callback, you should write code for sending email.

I think, a callback mechanism like is the only solution for what you are opting for and if you want everything to be written in same code block, then i you can make use of [blocks in objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid of that.  My issue is that I don't need the alert view in all circumstances, and I only need to check it once the email call has been made.  I guess I could structure it have the email constructed in a method that is called from either send mail or the call back from the alert view and have the send mail check the condition and determine to go directly to the actual construction method or the alert view..

Comment: Yes, you are correct..U should have a separate method for sending email if ready to send and that can be called either from the sendEmail method or from the callback method.

Answer (score 0):

The flow needs to be designed so that when the email is prompted it has set everything up and created a window with a button, at that point your code has finished and is not doing anything. Then when the button is pressed the next function/method is called that uses the data that was prepared before hand.

Answer (score 0):

I use MB Progress HUD 
 https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

i guess it is what you are looking for. It will show a loader which puts like overlay over the view in which it is added to.
You can use it like this :

In your Interface add

```
 MBProgressHUD *HUD;
```

Then call this when even you need

```
-(void) showHUD {
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Please Wait ...";
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    [self.tableView addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD show:YES];
}
```

And finally to hide it

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.tableView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks - but I don't think this would work for what I am intending to do.  Basically I want to selectively pop up an entry modal where the user can add some text to add to the email, only in certain circumstances.  Basically I want to check a condition and if true pop up the overlay to get the info, and if not continue without it.  I likely could use a callback, but I would prefer to handle it in the send method.